# Libinput support and input lag (joystick)

Tags: libinput

I feel joystick is more responsive than pointer, keyboard, etc.

But where is joystick libinput configuration, inputclass ?

Has libinput (pointer, keyboard, etc) anything with input lag?

If joystick works with no libinput mention, why we need it for mouse, keyboard and whatever?

Any idea?

Thx

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David Ubuntu 22.04 LTS